# Show $G(T^k,\lambda^k) \subseteq G(T,\lambda)$ for generalised eigenspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on complex vector space $V$ and $G(T,\lambda)$ denote the $\lambda$  generalised eigenspace for $T$.  Show $G(T^k,\lambda^k)= G(T,\lambda)$.

I have trouble proving $G(T^k,\lambda^k) \subseteq G(T,\lambda)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Hi can you explain?  I don't see why $\ker((T^k -\lambda^k I)^n)=\ker((T -\lambda I)^n)$

Comment: this seems wrong, consider the case where $T=I$, $\lambda =-1$, $k=2$, we have that $G(T^{k}, \lambda^{k})$ is the entire space but $G(T, \lambda)=\{0\}$